# как исправть ошибку Unity

Tags: unity3d

уже долгое время не могу решить проблему, мне дали код который при прикосновении рестартает игру вот он

```
public class RestartGameOnTouch : MonoBehaviour   
{   
    // Прикрепите этот скрипт к объекту, который должен перезапускать игру при касании   
   
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)   
    {   
        // Проверяем, коснулся ли игрок объекта с этим скриптом   
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))   
        {   
            // Перезапускаем игру   
            RestartGame();   
        }   
    }   
   
    void RestartGame()   
    {   
        // Здесь можно добавить любую логику, которая должна быть выполнена перед перезапуском игры   
        // Например, сбросить счетчики, сбросить позицию игрока и т. д.   
   
        // Перезапускаем сцену   
        UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene(UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);   
    }   
}
```

далее я сделал этот скрипт прикрепил всё куда надо колайдеры сделал но всё равно пишет ошибку

> Assets\Scenes\triger.cs(1,35): error CS0246: The type or namespace
> name 'MonoBehaviour' could not be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?)

что делать?

Comment: Скорее всего нужно импортировать нужные библиотеки, например UnityEngine;

Answer (score -1):

Во-первых, ты можешь попробовать подключить библиотеки *C#*, которые даны самим же *Unity*.

Во-вторых, функция перезапуска должна быть по-хорошему в другом файле.

На этом всё, я постарался объяснить проблему, а проблем с синтаксисом я не увидел.